# Does Flash have equivalent of tag property like for .net winform controls?

Tags: flash, actionscript

In winform you can have a tag property which is a custom property where you can put any stuff you want so that you don't need to create a custom component just for adding a new property.

Is this exist in Flash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm exactly understanding you, but it sounds like you want the ability to add a property to a custom class without having to declare that property in the class definition?

If that's the case, you'll want to use the "Dynamic" keyword on your class. "public dynamic class MyClass extends Whatever" - then you can say var myInstance:MyClass = new MyClass() and you can say myInstance.randomPropertyThatIJustMadeUp = whatever.

Does that make sense? Is that what you're looking for? Note that certain AS3 core classes already dynamic, including Object and MovieClip.

Finally, note that there is a good reason why that's not turned on by default. It's often not the best practice to use dynamic classes, it can slow down the player and lead to errors because you are negating the benefits of type checking. There are cases, though, where it's useful.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry saw your answer only today. I forgot to say that tag property is attached to standard control. Can I extend flash control with property ?